# How can I check if a route (ASP.NET MVC) exists for a given path?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a list of local URL’s and I need to determine if they are “valid MVC paths”. How can I check if a URL (path) maps to a MVC controller?

[Phil Haack's Route Debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx) will find a route that match the current request and does so using the current HttpContext. I would like to get this info without building up a mock HttpContext - if possible.

Comment: Type the path into the browser and check for 404?

Comment: Do you want to check whether they're valid paths or valid MVC paths?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can call `RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData` with a mocked HttpContextBase.

The routes are matched internally using the request's `AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath`.
However, this functionality is not exposed, so you need to pass an `HttpContextBase`.

You need to create an `HttpContextBase` class which returns an `HttpRequestBase` instance in its request property.
The `HttpRequestBase` class needs to return your path, beginning with `~/`, in its `AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath` property.

You don't need to implement any other properties, unless they're used by `IRouteConstraint`s.

To check whether you got an MVC route, check whether the resulting `routeData.Handler is MvcRouteHandler`.

Comment: Do what parts would I need to mock?

Comment: @mawtex: Create an `HttpContextBase` class which returns your URL in its `Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath`.

Comment: I found your mention of the required  AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath very valuable as I am writing tests for this now.  Wish I could vote up more than once :)

Comment: Do you have a code sample to demosntrate?

Comment: This is absolutely ancient now, but in the past, I used code based on this person's blog that uses this technique: https://blog.olamisan.com/how-to-determine-if-an-arbitrary-url-matches-a-defined-route. My minor extension to it: https://gist.github.com/lethek/9613978fa4ee7935bf34f9e68111e990