# Confirm that a route is in use in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, routes

I am wanting to do customer routes for users where they get to pick their url name.

http://example.com/customer-name

Can I validate that the name they input isn't already registered in our routes?  Like if someone typed "about", http://example.com/about, I could tell them that name is already in use because we have an About page.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a greedy route for the user defined routes.  The route registration would look like:

```
routes.MapRoute("customCustomerRoute",
                "{*customerName}", 
                new { controller = "Customer", action = "Home" }
        );
```

and should go at the end of your routes, so that it doesn't get eat up other routes.

You can then have the customer name paths stored in a db, and look up that path before the user wants to create a new one.

You could get all possible existing routes with the following code:

```
var routes = new RouteCollection();
MvcApplication.RegisterRoutes(routes);
```

Then, you could see if those routes contain the url to be registered.

Comment: But if I want to check that the route "/about" isn't in use, that wouldnt be in the DB, it would be in the Global.asax.

Comment: That just registers the routes?

Comment: It registers them in that route collection.  Then you could iterate through that route collection and see if that url already exists.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4882324/how-can-i-check-if-a-route-asp-net-mvc-exists-for-a-given-path

Answer (score 0):

I would place all the customer routes in a 'folder', ie. http://example.com/account/customer-name. No conflicts there.

Or place all other 'hardcoded' controllers in an area and prohibit this one for client use.