# Match a url to a route in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, routes

I am developing a REST API using ASP.NET and i need to accept a parameter in the body of a random POST request in the API that represents another API resource.

As for an example, Suppose we have:

`api/files
 api/operations`

Two resource representations that represent files and operations that can be performed on files.

Suppose i would like to accept an operation through POST request that merges two files, i would accept an object as following.

`operation {
name: 'merge',
parameters: 
['api/files/1', 'api/files/2']
}`

I would like to verify the urls submitted in the parameters array.
A first step would be match the urls to API routes so i can tell which resource the parameter target.

I created a sample ASP.NET Web API project using visual studio 2017 and debugged the following method. Nothing special except the "arrange" and "act" were taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37215782/6174341).

```
// GET api/values
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            // Arrange
            var context = new StubHttpContextForRouting(requestUrl: "~/api/values");

            // Act
            RouteData routeData = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(context);

            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }
```

The routeData always returns a route that has an empty template which i don't know why it is there.

[image: routeData debuging result]

This is not a duplicate of [Test if a request's URL is in the Route table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36894210/test-if-a-requests-url-is-in-the-route-table). Because that solution didn't work for me.

Is there any solution or alternative for this (except writing a helper parser for string url to match with routes) ?

Comment: api/operations/merge that takes a list of fileIds to merge would likely be easier to manage.

Comment: That was an example. Actually, i have multiple operations and i would like to be RESTful representing resources not actions.

Comment: Please show the code for `StubHttpContextForRouting`.

Comment: I referenced it in the thread already. it is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36894210/test-if-a-requests-url-is-in-the-route-table/37215782#37215782)